# Is there a correct way to hide a jQueryUI checkbox button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

I have a checkbox that I'm using with the jqueryui button widget and I would like to be able to show or hide it depending on other factors. However, I'm finding that .hide() doesn't work. Upon digging deaper, it appears that it doesn't work because caling .hide() on the checkbox would only affect the checkbox element and not the button element being displayed to the user.

I'm sure that I could use jquery and some knowledge of how the button is rendered to hide the element, but that becomes implementation dependent and I would prefer to avoid that so it doesn't break with a future version.

Alternatly, I could wrap the whole thing in some other element and show or hide that instead. This is probably the best idea of the ones I've been able to think of, but I'll have to play with the CSS to make sure that this extra element doesn't throw off the layout of the rest of the page.

Is there a correct way to do this?
Here is a jsfiddle showing that .hide() does not work.
http://jsfiddle.net/ormico/2zxde/

```
<label for="a">AAA</label><input id="a" type="checkbox"/>
<button id="h">Hide</button>

$("#a").button();

$("#h").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#a").hide();
});
```

Comment: why not give both the label and checkbox a class you can hide like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2zxde/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct it is only hiding the actual input element. If you also want to hide the label, (ui-widget). You could do something like @13ruce1337 said or something like this:

```
$("#a, label[for=a]").hide();
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gZjVc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

this work but i don't know why... put the html code into a div an hide/show this

```
<div id="pre"><input id="a" type="checkbox"/><label for="a">AAA</label></div>
<button id="h">Hide</button>
```

and jquery

```
$("#a").button();

$("#h").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#pre").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for your button/checkbox here : http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-destroy

You can do it this way :

```
$("#a").button();

$("#h").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // destroy jQueryUI button
    $("#a").button('destroy');
    // and then hide the original checkbox
    $("#a").hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple: the button consists of 2 DOM elements in your html tree.

Simply call `hide()` and `show()` on both instead of just 1:

```
$("label").hide();
$("#a").hide();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2zxde/16/

Comment: That works but is dependent on how jqueryui implements the control. Technically, the checkbox is already hidden and I just need to hide the label, but I was hoping for a way of doing this that might not break in a future version of jqueryui. But your code works.

Comment: No `jQueryUI` code removes anything from your HTML tree, it just *appends* to it. While you're right - it is possible, I find it highly doubtful they ever will, as it would make any non-trivial application extremely fragile.

Comment: The commonly used (and sensible) way of doing it is to wrap them in a `<form>` or `<div>`, and there's @napster3world's answer already saying it. I thought I would offer this alternative as you say you'd prefer a solution with no new HTML.